# Leaflet geoJson layer draw under the road name

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I use `L.geoJSON(feature).addTo(mymap);` to add road line ,

but the geoJson line will draw on the road name of the map,

I want to make the geoJson line draw under the road name of the map,

how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Are the names part of the basemap? If so, then you can't do anything about it. If names are their own layer, you can change their order by using `bringToFront` or `bringToBack` on them.

Answer (score 0):

I set style opacity to fix the problem.

```
var h = L.geoJSON(feature).addTo(mymap);
h.setStyle({weight:14,opacity:0.2});
```

[image]